# Random Letter Sequence Generator

Tags: vb.net

I had generated random numbers in `VB` as a part of the game. now i need a random sequence of `letters`. i did it with the help of a string array and a random numbers. but it is not the proper way for this, suggest me some more easier ways to generate the sequence.

Expected output will be [Like this](http://www.dave-reed.com/Nifty/randSeq.html)

i Use the code for generating such strings of length 5 is:

```
Dim s() As String = {"A", "R", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"}
Dim numberRandom As New Random()
Dim outPutString As String = ""
For i As Integer = 0 To 5
    outPutString = outPutString & s(numberRandom.Next(1, 10))
Next
MsgBox(outPutString)
```

Hope that their may be much better way for generating such sequence,

Edit:

- **Can i generate random sequence of letters without such string array?**
- **is it possible to generate random letters without using random numbers?**

thanks in advance

Comment: you need to clarify your post - how does the code posted not do what you want?  what is the desired output?  a "like this" link doesnt tell us anything

Comment: How is this not a proper way? It does the job, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how random you need the letters to be (ie, do they need to pass a stochastic test, etc), but for a start, I'd recommend getting a random number between 1 and 26, and map that to an array of the entire alphabet.

Alternatively, you can do the VB equivalent of int-to-string, and first adding the required character table offset to a random number in the 1-26 range.

I'm not sure if you're after speed or true randomness or ease of implementation, but both of the above should offer a reasonable alternative.

Comment: @ roelofs: this is not the answer this is the explanation for my question, actually this is the same method which i had implemented

Comment: I just saw that you added some edits.  The second alternative I gave, basically allows you to go straight from random number to random letter without an array, and is a little bit of a cheat in terms of getting a letter directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UUIDs.

```
GUID.NewGuid.ToString
```